# How to send manytomany field to Django rest framework using HTTP request in flutter

Tags: python, django, flutter, http, dart

I have a back end system that needs to receive a list of ids to fit a `manytomany` field made by django.

Here are my files :

**model**

```py
class field(models.Model):
    # Fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

class Lawyer(models.Model):
    # Relationships
    fields = models.ManyToManyField("mohamena_app.field") # << -- this is the targeted field
    city = models.ForeignKey("mohamena_app.City", on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    # Fields
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=4000)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True)
    lawyer_id = models.ImageField(upload_to="upload/images/")
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="upload/images/")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    is_phone_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activation_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='0000')
```

**Serializer**

```py
class LawyerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Lawyer
        fields = [
            "last_updated",
            "bio",
            "lawyer_id",
            "full_name",
            "fields",
            "city",
            "is_active",
            "image",
            "mobile",
            "created",
        ]
```

And here is how i tried to send the request in my flutter app :

```dart
  Future lawyerRegister(LawyerRegisterModel lawyerRegisterModel) async {
    Client client = Client();
    String theUrl = '${baseURL}Lawyer/';
    var uri = Uri.parse(theUrl);
    List fieldsList = [];
    for (FieldModel item in lawyerRegisterModel.fields){
      fieldsList.add(item.id); // Creates a list of IDS
    }
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Token $theToken',
    };
    var theRequest = MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
      theRequest.headers.addAll(headers);
      theRequest.fields['fields'] = '$fieldsList'; // Here is the error causing line 
      theRequest.fields['city'] = '${lawyerRegisterModel.cityID}';
      theRequest.fields['bio'] = '${lawyerRegisterModel.bio}';
      theRequest.fields['full_name'] = '${lawyerRegisterModel.fullName}';
      theRequest.fields['mobile'] = '${lawyerRegisterModel.mobile}';
      theRequest.files.add(await MultipartFile.fromPath('lawyer_id', lawyerRegisterModel.lawyerIDImagePath));
      theRequest.files.add(await MultipartFile.fromPath('image', lawyerRegisterModel.personalImagePath));
    try {
      Response response = await Response.fromStream(await theRequest.send());
      Map<String, dynamic> responseData = await jsonDecode(response.body);
      return responseData;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    } finally {
      client.close();
    }
  }
```

So when I send it this way I get this response :

```
{fields: [Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str.]}
```

And when I changed the `HTTP` request line to be like this :

```dart
  theRequest.fields['fields'] = fieldsList;
```

I get this error :

```
A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'
```

**NOTE**

I am using `MultipartRequest` because I need to send files, so I can't use the normal `http.post` request.

Answer (score 0):

I think `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` ( [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) ) solve your problem

```
class LawyerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fields = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=field.objects.all(), many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Lawyer
        fields = [
            "last_updated",
            "bio",
            "lawyer_id",
            "full_name",
            "fields",
            "city",
            "is_active",
            "image",
            "mobile",
            "created",
        ]
```